# Why are all the doors on Ferenginar (the Ferengi home world) far shorter than the average Ferengi?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, ferengi

I was watching [DS9: Family Business](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_Business_(Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine)) when I noticed all the doors on Ferenginar are much shorter than the average Ferengi, causing them to crouch down every time they enter a room.

That's gotta be terrible for their backs! I understand that Ferengi are shorter than the average humanoid, but why would they make the doors on their *own* home world too short for themselves?!

[image]

There are some other examples 
 here [1](https://www.flickr.com/photos/155639361@N07/47466228021/in/dateposted-public/), [2](https://www.flickr.com/photos/155639361@N07/33589612628/in/dateposted-public/), [3](https://www.flickr.com/photos/155639361@N07/33589622468/in/dateposted-public/)

Comment: Good question. I wondered that at the time too. I suspect it's to make the houses look more like dens.

Comment: You don't need to tell us what kind of sources to use. If you have a look at the Star Trek tags, you'll find that those are what we already use.

Comment: Make them bowing when entering buildings.

Comment: I could have sworn that an episode mentioned that it was so visitors had to bow, but I can't find anything actually supporting that.

Comment: [Memory Alpha hypothesizes that it's a LoTR reference.](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Family_Business_(episode)#Trivia) But you seem to be looking for an in-universe explanation.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish Nice find, I wasn't aware of this

Comment: Maybe they're _really old_ doors? You can see similar real world examples of human doors that are lower than average height, in areas with buildings that are centuries old. This is because humans have got significantly taller over time.

Comment: Ferenginar's weather is known for torrential rains and rivers of muck.  If dens (either presently or traditionally) are air tight, having doors below head level would ensure in the event of an overwhelming flood there's a bubble of air trapped inside that is breathable for those inside.  But this has no canon support I'm aware of so I can't put my rampant speculation as answer. :)

Comment: I would hazard a guess that it makes the doors cheaper to construct. :-)  And perhaps Ferengi don't suffer the same sort of back problems as hew-mons?  There's less weight and leverage on their spine which I imagine would help.

Comment: @NathanGriffiths you came to the same suspicion that I did. I went further to suspect that the reason they don't fix them, or even change the design in newer buildings, is that it would cost money.

Comment: It’s not _all_ doors. For enough latinum, you can have a door as tall as you want! The Doormaker’s Guild is very powerful.

Comment: It's not bad on your back if you do it properly.

Comment: They got a bulk discount on 3/4 height doors.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The [original script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/469.txt) describes them thusly;

> There are no windows, but there are a few doors leading to other parts
>   of the building.  **The doors are low and tunnel-like** and even Ferengi
>   have to stoop to get through them. Rain from Ferenginar's relentless
>   downpour can be heard beating against the roof.
>
> Quark and Rom ENTER, followed by Brunt.  Each Ferengi deposits a coin
>   in a collection box by the door, then removes a towel from a rack, and
>   begins blotting off the rain.

The fact that they look like tunnel entrances may be a nod to the fact that the Ferengi are more animalistic, living in literal dens that have been modernised.

---

I've seen [web-chatter](http://www.treknobabble.net/2013/07/deep-space-nine-season-3-family-business.html) that one of the EU novels mentions that the doorways became smaller over time as the Ferengi realised that they were among the shortest of the Alpha quadrant races, as a form of compensation for their obvious inferiority.

> I liked the explanation offered  in one of the books that Ferengi
>   doors are too short for them. **After gaining spaceflight and realizing
>   they are shorter than other humanoids, the trend for small doors
>   emerged as a way to make them feel taller in the same spaces.** I kind
>   of retroactively assumed that's what the designers were actually
>   thinking

Comment: And yes, I'm trying to track down the source of that reference.

Comment: In early medieval times, it was common to have low doors, forcing possible raiders to stoop to enter, making them easy targets.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen - If DS9: Little Green Men is anything to go by, the Ferengi haven't had any full scale wars in their history and certainly nothing that would necessitate defences in every home.

Comment: @Valorum And there's no modern reasons for battlements on buildings, and yet they're still semi-common on some mansions and other buildings. Nobody uses floppy disks anymore, but we still have pictures of them used as 'save' icons everywhere in our software. Very few still listen to music on tape or record and yet we still refer to songs on an album as a 'track'. Just because there's no real need for something anymore doesn't mean that need in the past wasn't the reason for a current tradition.

Comment: Also, especially from earlier TNG appearances, Ferengi seem to have, at least originally, been intended to scuttle about semi-hunched rather than walking properly upright.  By DS9 we see them increasingly walking fully upright like typical bipedal humans would, but this was not always the case.

Comment: @Shufflepants: Actually, Quark at one point tells us that the Ferengi have *never* had substantial wars on their planet.

Comment: @Kevin I thought he was making the argument against all antiquated reasons for having low doors, not just that particular possible explanation about raiders. But just because there were no substantial wars, doesn't mean there weren't possible small groups of bandits and raiders.